# E: Unable to locate package slave-gtk3

Tags: package-management, themes

I tried to install SLAVE GTK3 Theme and this is the error msg i am getting.
I used the command sudo apt-get install slave-gtk3 for the installation
Please someone help in this topic

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear to be a standard package. It certainly isn't in any of the standard repositories.

There is one PPA that I can find that provides it: https://launchpad.net/~upubuntu-com/+archive/gtk3

Obviously the standard stuff about PPAs applies. Your computer is only as secure as the software you run on it. PPAs are untrusted sources. Anyway, the choice is yours.

Comment: Hey I am new to linux i dont know how to add this repository please help me on that to.. and thanks in advance

Comment: Instructions are available at the link under the heading "Adding this PPA to your system", very close to the top.